# PolygonShape created at different position

Tags: flutter, game-physics, box2d, flame, forge2d

I'm trying to create a polygon at the center of the screen with a mouse joint, very simple.
A CircleShape works great. Also the mouse joint behaves strangely and I couldn't find a pattern.
All code is in the main file [here](https://github.com/adamkatav/test_flame/blob/main/lib/main.dart). I kept the code to a minimum.

```
Vector2 vec2Median(List<Vector2> vecs) {
  var sum = Vector2(0, 0);
  for (final v in vecs) {
    sum += v;
  }
  return sum / vecs.length.toDouble();
}

void main() {
  final game = MyGame();
  runApp(GameWidget(game: game));
}

class MyGame extends Forge2DGame with MultiTouchDragDetector, HasTappables {
  MouseJoint? mouseJoint;
  static late BodyComponent grabbedBody;
  late Body groundBody;

  MyGame() : super(gravity: Vector2(0, -10.0));

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final boundaries = createBoundaries(this); //Adding boundries
    boundaries.forEach(add);

    groundBody = world.createBody(BodyDef());
    final center = screenToWorld(camera.viewport.effectiveSize / 2);
    final poly = Polygon([
      center + Vector2(0, 0),
      center + Vector2(0, 5),
      center + Vector2(5, 0),
      center + Vector2(5, 5)
    ], bodyType: BodyType.dynamic);
    add(poly);
    grabbedBody = poly;
  }

  @override
  bool onDragUpdate(int pointerId, DragUpdateInfo details) {
    final mouseJointDef = MouseJointDef()
      ..maxForce = 3000 * grabbedBody.body.mass * 10 //Not neccerly needed
      ..dampingRatio = 1
      ..frequencyHz = 5
      ..target.setFrom(grabbedBody.body.position)
      ..collideConnected = false //Maybe set to true
      ..bodyA = groundBody
      ..bodyB = grabbedBody.body;

    mouseJoint ??= world.createJoint(mouseJointDef) as MouseJoint;

    mouseJoint?.setTarget(details.eventPosition.game);
    return false;
  }

  @override
  bool onDragEnd(int pointerId, DragEndInfo details) {
    if (mouseJoint == null) {
      return true;
    }
    world.destroyJoint(mouseJoint!);
    mouseJoint = null;
    return false;
  }
}

abstract class TappableBodyComponent extends BodyComponent with Tappable {
  final Vector2 position;
  final BodyType bodyType;
  TappableBodyComponent(this.position, {this.bodyType = BodyType.dynamic});

  @override
  bool onTapDown(_) {
    MyGame.grabbedBody = this;
    return false;
  }

  Body tappableBCreateBody(Shape shape) {
    final fixtureDef = FixtureDef(shape)
      ..restitution = 0.8
      ..density = 1.0
      ..friction = 0.4;

    final bodyDef = BodyDef()
      // To be able to determine object in collision
      ..userData = this
      ..angularDamping = 0.8
      ..position = position
      ..type = bodyType;

    return world.createBody(bodyDef)..createFixture(fixtureDef);
  }
}

class Polygon extends TappableBodyComponent {
  final List<Vector2> vertecies;

  Polygon(this.vertecies, {BodyType bodyType = BodyType.dynamic})
      : super(vec2Median(vertecies), bodyType: bodyType);

  @override
  Body createBody() {
    final shape = PolygonShape()..set(vertecies);
    return tappableBCreateBody(shape);
  }
}
```

tappableBCreateBody encapsulate Tappable and body creation methods, Polygon is the object I'm trying to create, vec2Median returns the center of the polygon (by vertices).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to remove `center` from the vertices and only add that as the position of the `BodyComponent` instead, like you already do in the super call of your `Polygon` class.

Comment: Thank you, It does makes more sense to place the vertices in relation to the position of the polygon. BTW, I love Flame :)

Comment: Glad you enjoy it, stay tuned for v1.1 which will be released in a few days!